# Problem in using shell for loop inside gnu make?

Tags: gnu-make, nested-loops

consider the below make file

```
all: 
     @for x in y z; \ 
     do \ 
          for a in b c; \
          do \
                   echo $$x$$a >> log_$$x; \
          done; \
     done
```

While executing this make file, two file got created log_y and log_z. log_y is having data "yb" and "yc". similarly log_z is having data"zb" and "zc".

Actually I want to create four files(log_y_b, log_y_c, log_z_b, log_z_c). For this i have modified the above make file as,

```
all:
     @for x in y z; \ 
     do \ 
          for a in b c; \
          do \
                   echo $$x$$a >> log_$$x_$$a; \
          done; \
     done
```

But its creating only one file log_.  What should i have to do to create four files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps put braces around the variable names: it works on my system.

```
all:
    @for x in y z; \
    do \
        for a in b c; \
        do \
            echo $$x$$a >> log_$${x}_$${a}; \
        done; \
    done
```

You can also use [foreach](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/make/Foreach-Function.html#Foreach-Function):

```
all:
    @$(foreach x,y z,$(foreach a,b c,echo $(x)$(a) >> log_$(x)_$(a);))
```

Comment: As ndim says, it's because the underscore character does not delimit the variable name. Also, take a look at [foreach](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/make/Foreach-Function.html#Foreach-Function) in the make manual. You can simplify your example in one line as: `$(foreach x,y z,$(foreach a,b c,echo $(x)$(a) >> log_$(x)_$(a);))` -- I'll put this in my answer above, for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

`log_$$x_$$a` in the *Makefile* turns into `log_$x_$a` for the shell which is equivalent to `log_${x_}${a}`. The variable `$x_` is undefined, however, so the shell substitutes it by the empty string.

Solution: Properly write the `$x` variable with curly braces around the name (`${variablename}`), i.e. for consistency's sake write `log_${x}_${a}` (or in *Makefile* style: `log_$${x}_$${a}`).